# Usage Estimation Algorithm on a Series (c#)

Tags: c#, distribution, estimation

We have a package delivery system. In which daily packages arrived or departed. We have these data. We want to estimate next day usage based on historical data(say 30 days)

Example Data
[image]

What is best algorithm to estimate next day usage. 
If there is implementation please provide.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [polynomial regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) is best used for predictions of the form you describe... or if you want a full blown solution look into [Google's Prediction API](https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs) ... here is an [interesting polynomial / correlation article](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#regression_and_correlation/polynomial.htm)